# Twitter Tweet Search FROM particular date to TO particular date wrt/ and without user using java api

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

I would like to search for a tweets within a range of between dates by using Twitter API v1.1

let Query query=new QUery(String query);

what is the query thats suits for my question ??

Thanks in advance for reply back.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest setting [`until`](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/Query.html#setUntil-java.lang.String-) to limit your query to an upper date bound, e.g.:

```
query.setUntil("2014-07-01");
```

Then step back through the result set, by making subsequent search calls, until you hit your lower date bound.

Be aware that the search API may not contain all Tweets and it may not 'go back' as far as you need. For more information on it, and other query parameters, take a look at [Twitter's documentation on searching](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets).